# Build and run Qt 6 software on Windows 7

Tags: qt, windows-7, qt6

Has someone successfully developed Qt 6 applications under Windows 7 or at least was able to run and deploy them on Windows 7 after building them on Windows 10? I khow that there is no official support of Win7/8 in Qt 6 but it would be useful to have a workaround.

Comment: It's not just "we don't support win7". I was looking into `qtbase` commit messages and they are indeed removing code for windows 7 support.

Comment: [Here](https://forum.qt.io/topic/133002/qt-creator-6-0-1-and-qt-6-2-2-running-on-windows-7/) you go.